# Need faster code for replacing strings with values from dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nltk, sklearn-pandas

This is how i applied dictionary for stemming. My dictionary (d) is imported and it's in this format now `d={'nada.*':'nadas', 'mila.*':'milas'}`
I wrote this code to stemm tokens, but it runs TOO SLOW, so i stopped it before it finished. I guess it's problem because dict is large, and there is large number of tokens. 
So, how can i implement my stem dictionary, so that code can run normaly?
I tried to find a method in nltk package to apply custom dict, but i didn't find it.

```
#import stem dict
d = {}
with open("Stem rečnik.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       key, val = line.split(":")
       d[key.replace("\n","")] = val.replace("\n","")

#define tokenizer
def custom_tokenizer(text):
    #split- space
    tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(text)
    #stemmer
    for i, token in enumerate(tokens):
        for key, val in d.items():
            if re.match(key, token):
                tokens[i] = val
                break
    return tokens
```

Dictionary sample:

```
bank.{1}$:banka
intes.{1}$:intesa
intes.{1}$:intesa
intez.{1}$:intesa
intezin.*:intesa
banke:banka
banaka:banka
bankama:banka
```

post_text sample:

```
post_text = [
    'Banca intesa #nocnamora',
    'Banca intesa',
    'banka haosa i neorganizovanosti!',
    'Cucanje u banci umesto setnje posle rucka.',
    "Lovin' it #intesa'"
]
```

Comment: Please provide `d` to make this a [mcve]. Why use `re.match` instead of just string matching? Or even better: check whether `token  in d`—searches in O(1) time instead of O(n).

Comment: it's because key is regex. Oh, that's a nice one, i will check now how it works...Can u tell me, how it searches token in d, cause d is a list of pairs, like i wrote?

Comment: You provided code that defines `d` for you.  But it reads a file that we can't see.  You need to either forgo the file reference and provide a direct definition of a dictionary, or provide the contents of that file.  Also, you should provide a sample of `text` that you are passing to  the function `custom_tokenizer`.  Think of a [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) this way, I need to be able to copy and paste the code you've provided into my system and it needs to run.  If you have any reference to information that I can't see, it won't run.

Comment: Are all the regex patterns like that, ie. the stem followed by zero or more characters? (`stem.*`)

Comment: @hope94 `d` is a dict, not a list of pairs.

Comment: Dictionary contains 500 pairs of words, where to put that? And text that gets cv is a list of 5500 sentences. So i guess you mean a couple of each to provide?

Comment: Yes, enough to be a complete but *minimal* example.

Comment: You don't need to provide **ALL** the data.  Just some of it so we can see what's going on.  Chop some data out such that it still runs.  If you think that is hard?  Maybe it is, but it's what will help get your question answered.  And you have to decide how important that is to you.

Comment: Considering I can use `d={'nada.*':'nadas', 'mila.*':'milas'}` as a sample dictionary, I still would like some sample text.

Comment: The only obvious optimization I can see is to pre-[compile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) all your regexes: `d[re.compile(key)] = val.replace("\n","")`

Comment: post_text=['Banca intesa #nocnamora', 'Banca intesa','banka haosa i neorganizovanosti!','Cucanje u banci umesto setnje posle rucka.', 'Lovin' it #intesa'] 
--------------dictionary: bank.{1}$:banka intes.{1}$:intesa   intez.{1}$:intesa

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy i tried both, but that didn't work. It returns the same tokens that i gave as input. 
The only thing that worked was this to  pre-compile all regexes: d[re.compile(key)] = val.replace("\n","").
But code still runs slow, about 10-15 minutes...

Answer (score 0):

Notice that while the keys in your stem dict are regexes, they all start with a short string of some specific characters.  Let's say the minimum length of specific characters is 3.  Then, construct a dict like this:

```
'ban' : [('bank.$', 'banka'),
         ('banke', 'banka'),
         ('banaka', 'banka'),
         ('bankama', 'banka'),
        ],
'int' : [('inte[sz].$', 'intesa'),
         ('intezin.*', 'intesa'),
        ],
```

Of course, you should `re.compile()` all those patterns at the beginning.

Then you can do a cheaper, three-character lookup in this dict:

```
def custom_tokenizer(text):
    tokens = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(text)
    for i, token in enumerate(tokens):
        for key, val in d.get(token[:3], []):
            if re.match(key, token):
                tokens[i] = val
                break
    return tokens
```

Now instead of checking all 500 stems, you only need to check the few that start with the right prefix.